# Перенос словаря в таблицу excel с помощью python

Tags: python, excel, словари, xls

Не могу найти решение для заполнения таблицы в Excel данными из словаря с помощью Python. Так, чтобы ключи словаря были названиями колонок, а значения - по строкам.
Имею словарь примерно такого вида на 3000 строк.

Не нахожу ничего подходящего(
Спасибо!
[image: пример таблицы Excel]

```
{
  "ver" : "2.0",
  "forma" : "PU2",
  "unpf" : "102030",
  "unp" : "1000102040",
  "plat" : "ОOO \МТ\",
  "type" : 1,
  "kv" : 3,
  "year" : "2019",
  "pck" : "PU2_1052_10051_1_201901_20191010101010",
  "tel" : "10101010",
  "ddoc" : "10/10/2019",
  "data" : [ {
    "ils" : "10203060",
    "fzl" : "ИВАНОВ",
    "izl" : "Е",
    "ozl" : "С",
    "r2" : [ {
      "prof2" : "7101-138-11-5-01",
      "dpr21" : "",
      "npr21" : "",
      "dfr21" : "",
      "kod" : "",
      "dpr22" : "13/10/2019",
      "npr22" : "103",
      "dfr22" : "10/10/2019"
    } ]
},
{
    "ils" : "306090",
    "fzl" : "ПЕТРОВИЧ",
    "izl" : "П",
    "ozl" : "А",
    "r1" : [ {
      "dfr1" : "",
      "dpr11" : "",
      "npr11" : "",
      "sovm" : "",
      "dto1" : "31/08/2019",
      "koduv1" : "1.2",
      "dpr12" : "30/09/2019",
      "npr12" : "687"
    } ]
},
{
    "ils" : "78B8",
    "fzl" : "ШАЗНЮК",
    "izl" : "И",
    "ozl" : "С",
    "r1" : [ {
      "dfr1" : "10/07/2019",
      "dpr11" : "25/10/2019",
      "npr11" : "3105",
      "sovm" : "0",
      "dto1" : "",
      "koduv1" : "",
      "dpr12" : "",
      "npr12" : ""
    } ],
    "r2" : [ {
      "prof2" : "1010-071-02-0-01",
      "dpr21" : "10/09/2019",
      "npr21" : "3107",
      "dfr21" : "24/10/2019",
      "kod" : "1",
      "dpr22" : "",
      "npr22" : "",
      "dfr22" : ""
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Хорошо приложить как вы это видите в Эксель. Самый простой способ сохранить в csv файл.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/E4PHG

Comment: т.е. одно поле словаря это список. Нужно продублировать для каждого элемента списка значения в полях элемента? Мне кажется выбрана неудачная структура данных для этого, кроме того в вашем примере некорректно отображаются значения полей.

Comment: вам поможет библиотека openpyxl

Comment: У вас крайне не удобная структура данных для отображения в Excel. Да и вопрос, на самом деле, стоит не в том, чем это записать, а как это отобразить в двумерном виде. Я считаю, что в вашем случае проще написать преобразователь ваших словарей в двумерную таблицу, и уже ее писать в Excel. Ну или какой-то класс-маппер, который вложенные словари будет отображать в виде многоуровневой шапки таблицы. Но готовых инструментов я не встречал.

Comment: Да я уже пытался транспонирование данных в Excel сделать. Тоже ничего толкового не выходит. Структура данных придумана государством, хотелось сделать отображение в удобном для сверки-проверки данных виде